# Thumbnail image swap on mousemove

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, mousemove

I would love to have a gallery website with multiple thumbnails including 3 images that rotate as soon as I mousemove over each one.

I've found this amazing responsive fiddle in another thread from @matthias_h going through multiple thumbnail images while mousemove over the thumbnail box.

His fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/2f2tth47/

The HTML

```
<article>
<figure data-image-list="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/cccccc.png&text=img1,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/dedede/cccccc.png&text=img2,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/b31031/cccccc.png&text=img3">
    <img class="imageHolder" data-src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" />
</figure>
```

The Javascript

```
$(".imageHolder").mousemove(function (event) {
var xPos = event.pageX,
    imgPos = $(".imageHolder").offset().left,
    imgWidth = $(".imageHolder").width();
console.log("xPos: ", xPos, ", imgPos: ", imgPos, ", imgWidth: ", imgWidth);
var change1 = imgPos,
    change2 = imgPos + imgWidth / 3,
    change3 = imgPos + 2 * imgWidth / 3;
console.log("change1: ", change1, "change2: ", change2, "change3: ", change3);
$images = $("figure").data("imageList");

var array = $images.split(',');
if (xPos > change1) {
    $("img").attr("src", array[0]);
}
if (xPos > change2) {
    $("img").attr("src", array[1]);
}
if (xPos > change3) {
    $("img").attr("src", array[2]);

}});$("img").mouseout(function (){$("img").attr("src", $("img").data("src"));});
```

Unfortunately there are two issues with this.

1. When duplicating it, moving over any of them also switches the
   images on the other ones.
2. It takes single images instead of bg positions via css which is less efficient since I'm personally using image sprites for all my work.

I have good experience with html/css but no experience with javascript. Would love to get some insight how I can fix these two issues. Mainly the first one to make a gallery with multiple images work in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you duplicated the elements, it is targeting a collection instead of just one element.

In general, jQuery method's **setter** applies to all matching elements, and **getter** return a value for the first matching element.

Question #1:
Use
`$(this)` instead of `$("img")`
`$(this)` instead of `$(".imageHolder")`
`$(this).parent("figure")` instead of `$("figure")`

Question #2:
You will have to use `.css()` to change the background position instead of changing the href.
That would be something like `$(this).css({background-position: newPosition})` where `newPosition` has to be defined...

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yLvqzRj?editors=0011)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried to replace everything for #1 but it didn't work. Am I missing something that I also have to change up in the script?

Comment: I appreciate your insight so much! Everything is working so far. But now I came up with an overlay to display information inside the thumbnail. But just replacing the imageHolder with the new overlay class doesn't work. Any idea how I can adjust it? https://jsfiddle.net/t2qw9b10/

Comment: Now that you added an overlay, when you pass the mouse over the image, that overlay is in between. So just change `$(".imageHolder").mousemove(...)` to `$(".imageHolder, .author").mousemove(...)` --- Then, inside the handler, `$(this)` may be the image OR the overlay... So from `$(this)` you have to get a wider parent to find the image. Here is [your Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/guLw80zj/1/).